# Java compiler ignores type safety

Tags: java, oop, generics, types, type-safety

```
public class POJO<T> {

    private List<Integer> integer = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public POJO() {
        integer.add(1);
        integer.add(2);
    }

    public List<Integer> getInteger() {
        return integer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        POJO pojo = new POJO();
        List<String> integer = pojo.getInteger(); // No compile error?
        System.out.println(integer); // prints [1, 2]
    }
}
```

How is it possible for the following line to compile:

```
List<String> integer = pojo.getInteger();
```

Provided `getInteger()` is typed as following

```
public List<Integer> getInteger()
```

Comment: Your class declaration makes no sense: `POJO<DateOrString extends Date & CharSequence>`---this constrains the type param to a subtype of **both** `Date` and `CharSequence`, but from its name it seems you are expecting that it will allow **any** of the two.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It works if POJO is instantiated without generics.

Comment: @assylias How come? In that case it ignores **any** generic type information, even those that have nothing to do with the class's type param? Strange.

Comment: @assylias Checked it, just emits a warning. Didn't know about that. If it's a static method, then it emits an error. This is worthy of a Java Puzzler.

Comment: @Farmor I have significantly edited your question to provide a simpler example that shows the same behaviour. Feel free to rollback if you don't like it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - they could probably do a whole book of generics puzzlers :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a reference in the [JLS 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8-210) that backs up what @PeterLawrey says:

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

So all instance methods of your raw `POJO` object are erased, including those that don't reference the type `T` of `POJO<T>`, which means ([JLS 4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6-210)):

> The type parameters of a  [...] method (§8.4.4), and the return type (§8.4.5) of a method, also undergo erasure if the [...] method's signature is erased.

Answer (score 6):

As `pojo` is not declared as a generic

```
POJO pojo = new POJO();
```

the compiler assumes you are using it in pre-generic code. i.e. where generics were added after the code was written. So when you do

```
List<String> integer = pojo.getInteger();
```

You get a warning rather than an error.

i.e. If the type is non-generic, all generic checks are turn off, not just those which relate to the type you didn't give it.  I believe this is for maximum backward compatibility.

For comparison.

```
Map mapOfInteger = new Map(); // no generics
Set<String> entries = map.entrySet(); // gives a warning, not an error.
```

In this example, You might expect `Set<Entry<K, V>>` to become `Set<Entry>` if not generic, but the compiler falls back to treating the class a non-generic `Set`.

Comment: So here we finally have a definite, clear difference between `POJO` and `POJO<?>`.

Comment: Just one comment: your line with `map.keySet()` is not as strong an example as original, where the method returns a definite `List<Integer>`. `keySet()` only returns `Set<K>`, so without `K` provided, that always made sense to me. This one is more of a head-scratcher.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `entrySet()` is a better example.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I like it clean and clear so I found the JLS reference that backs up your claims ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is an unchecked assignment that is not treated as error for compatibility reasons.

See [Interoperating with Legacy Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/legacy.html)

> In reality, the assignment is legal, but it generates an unchecked warning.